# Application crashes as dll not compatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a VS2010 C++ application and When I execute, it crashes with below error:
`dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains an error.`

I link to the dll which resides in Windows server 2008 64bit .But I execute my application in 32bit windows7.Should this be the reason for this? If so what should be the solution for this?

Any help would be really helpful as i am new to VS2010.

Comment: It is high time to update your dev machine.

Answer (score 3):

You CAN NOT mix 64-bit DLL's with 32-bit applications or vice versa. You will need to build the app as 64-bit, or find/build a version of the DLL that is 32-bit.

And you also can't use a 64-bit DLL on a 32-bit OS - so the option of "compiling the application for 64-bit" is not really an option in this case.

Comment: Thanks..i had tried to build the app, by setting target platform as x64.But then i get "Unresolved External Symbol" error for the functions those are part of the dlls.I think i am missing something else in configuration setup.

Comment: you're probably still linking against the 32bit import library instead of the 64 bit one

Comment: In configuration setup i have given the target platform as x64. But when i check the WIN32 macro it comes as #define WIN32 1. So i think though i have given x64 option internally its taking win32 only..am i missing something here to build the application as x64?